# Crear trigger para actualizar un campo calculado

Tags: mysql, trigger, base-de-datos

tengo la siguiente tabla:

```
create table ClIENTES (ID int unsigned AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
CODIGO_TARJETA decimal (16) not null,
TELEFONO decimal (9) not null,
EMAIL varchar (40),
NOMBRE varchar (20),
DIRECCION varchar (50)
GASTO decimal (9) not null) engine=innodb;
```

Y me gustaría poder actualizar el gasto de cada cliente con un trigger cada  vez que este compre un producto. Y sí, tiene que ser con un trigger aunque se pueda hacer de otra forma. Gracias.
No tengo practicamente nada de codigo hecho porque estoy muy atascado, o al menos eso pienso yo. Esto es todo lo que tengo:

```
DROP TRIGGER actualiza; 
delimiter // 
CREATE TRIGGER actualiza AFTER INSERT, UPDATE ON CLIENTES 
BEGIN
```

hago que el trigger se ejecute después de insertar o actualizar la tabla clientes pero no se como actualizar solo el gasto, ¿o solo con esto ya se actualiza?

Comment: El trigger lo estás poniendo sobre la tabla CLIENTES, lo tendrías que poner sobre la tabla donde insertás la compra para que se dispare cuando haya una compra nueva. Y desde ahi hacer un update al campo gasto de la tabla de clientes, sumando el importe de la venta (o restando si es update o un delete que da vuelta la operación).

Comment: Intentaré eso gracias.

Comment: He creado una función que me saca el gasto de cada cliente y con eso quiero hacer el trigger, si es posible claro.

Answer (score 0):

Estoy complementado, lo que quiero decir es que he intentado esto y no me sale.
La siguiente tabla sería la que tendría que usar:

create table VENDER (ID int unsigned AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,

CANTIDAD varchar (20),

TIPO_COMPRA varchar (20),

FECHA varchar (10),

FORMA_DE_PAGO varchar (20),

ID_DEPENDIENTES INT UNSIGNED,

FOREIGN KEY (ID_DEPENDIENTES) REFERENCES DEPENDIENTES (ID) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,

CODIGO_ROPA INT UNSIGNED, FOREIGN KEY (CODIGO_ROPA) REFERENCES ROPA (ID) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,

ID_CLIENTES INT UNSIGNED, FOREIGN KEY (ID_CLIENTES) REFERENCES CLIENTES (ID)

ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE) engine=innodb;

para poder usarla para actualizar el campo calculado de GASTO de la tabla CLIENTES debería usar un JOIN con el ID de la tabla clientes y el ID_CLIENTES de esta tabla, ¿es correcto? ¿Sería usar un UPDATE o tendría que poner un SET?

Comment: Por favor, los comentarios a tu pregunta añádelos en la sección comentarios, o bien editando la pregunta.

Comment: Tienes razón, estoy complementado, lo que quería decir es que he intentado eso y no me sale.

Answer (score 0):

He creado una función que me calcula el GASTO, esta función me funciona correctamente, a partir de ella he creado un trigger para actualizar el GASTO de la siguiente forma:

DROP TRIGGER actualiza;

delimiter //

CREATE TRIGGER actualiza AFTER UPDATE ON CLIENTES FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

IF new.GASTO IS !=0

THEN

UPDATE CLIENTES SET GASTO=GASTO+new.GASTO WHERE GASTO IN (SELECT gasto);

END IF;

END;//

DELIMITER ;

Comment: estas respondiendo a tu pregunta o complementandola?